# Correct way to ask boss to decrease from full-time to part-time

Tags: work-time

I've been working in the company for 1 year. I don't feel happy anymore working there. Also I didn't have any salary raise.

I don't depend much of this company because I work for other too(One company doesn't know about the other). So I was thinking about decreasing my time in the former and increase in the latter( Maybe getting a counter proposal in the proccess? I know my company is looking for new employees for months but it's hard to find good ones). And I'll start to look for something new too.

But how should I tell my boss I want to work for less hours? The correct way so I don't leave a bad impression.

Comment: Isn't a salary raise quite unlikely within the first year?

Comment: What country do you live in? There can be differences, both cultural and legal. Also, not informing a company about other employment might be a breach of your employment contract.

Comment: Why not talk to the Other company first? If you enjoy that one more, consider seeing if they will give you a full time position and then just resign from this one

Comment: It's a very uncommon case. I live in Brazil, and work for a company in Japan. The employers at japan have a better salary, because they adjusted my salary to my living costs. But I perform better than most of them, is it fair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how should I tell my boss I want to work for less hours? The
>   correct way so I don't leave a bad impression.

That depends on your boss.

The most obvious way is to be direct. Something like "Boss, I'd like to change from full time to part time. I'm busy doing some other things so I think that would work out best for me." might work.

But it probably depends on how much they rely on your work as a full timer. Some job situations need a full-timer to hold the position and a part-timer wouldn't be viable. In some cases it would be better to find yourself a new part-time job instead of trying to change this one.

You are in the best position to judge what might work and what wouldn't.

You need to be prepared with how you will answer if they reply "No". And there's a (perhaps small) chance that you will be fired, if local laws permit it.

Before doing anything, you need to decide how likely it is that your other employer will increase your hours enough.

Comment: I forgot to tell, one company doesn't know about the other.